# how to implement in-app browser with react native?

Tags: react-native

How to make in-app browser in react-native?

Basically we are opening our website in default browser like so `Linking.openUrl`.

But i need to implement in-app browser ( Web Page within an app ). 
How do i can do it? [image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did in my app is couple a [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) with a [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html)

So your user do not leave the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [InAppBrowser system](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser) for React Native, using SafariViewController and ChromeTabs to support both platforms (iOS and Android).

Comment: How can I control this with something like onNavigationStateChange which is available for a simple webview?

Comment: You can't do that with Native code using the browser, sorry